# How can I create a tarball with UID/GID of root?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to amend this code so that the UID and GID of the files inserted into the tarball belong to root.

```
import tarball

sources = [ 'test-directory', 'another-directory/file1' ]

with tarfile.open("/tmp/test.tar","w") as tarball:
    for source in sources:
        tarball.add(source)
```

`sources` is mixed list of directory and filenames.  With the above code, all the files are there, but with my user UID and GID.  If I were doing this on the command line, I'd prefix a call to `tar` with `fakeroot`.

In Python (3), if I try just looking at one directory:

```
import tarfile
import glob

with tarfile.open("/tmp/test.tar","w") as tarball:
    for filename in glob.iglob('test-directory/**', recursive=True):
        info = tarball.gettarinfo(filename)
        info.uid = 0
        info.gid = 0
        info.uname = 'root'
        info.gname = 'root'
        tarball.addfile(info)
```

That gets me proper ownership but it's missing files in the `test-directory` tree because I can't get the glob to working satisfactorily.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the source (`tarfile.py`)

I added this function based on inspecting the `add()` method from the above.

```
        def add_tarinfo(tarball, tarinfo, name, arcname, fakeroot):
            if fakeroot:
                tarinfo.uid = 0
                tarinfo.gid = 0
                tarinfo.uname = 'root'
                tarinfo.gname = 'root'
            if tarinfo.isreg():
                with open(name, "rb") as f:
                    tarball.addfile(tarinfo, f)
            elif tarinfo.isdir():
                tarball.addfile(tarinfo)
                for f in os.listdir(name):
                    nname = os.path.join(name, f)
                    narcname = os.path.join(arcname, f)
                    ntarinfo = tarball.gettarinfo(nname, narcname)
                    add_tarinfo(tarfile, ntarinfo, nname, narcname, fakeroot)
            else:
                tarball.addfile(tarinfo)
```

So the original code becomes:

```
  with tarfile.open("/tmp/test.tar","w") as tarball:
        for arcname in self.sources:
            name = os.path.join(self.source_path, arcname)
            tarinfo = tarball.gettarinfo(name=name, arcname=arcname)
            add_tarinfo(tarball, tarinfo, name, arcname, True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this using the `filter` parameter (available since Python 3.2) of `TarFile.add()` method ([docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.add)):

```
def fakeroot_filter(tarinfo):
    tarinfo.gid = 0
    tarinfo.uid = 0
    tarinfo.gname = 'root'
    tarinfo.uname = 'root'
    return tarinfo

with tarfile.open('data.tgz', 'w:gz', format=tarfile.GNU_FORMAT) as arc:
    arc.add(f'{path}/data', arcname='data', filter=fakeroot_filter)
```

Some additional info about this feature can be found in the [related issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue6856) on bugs.python.org